# Java while loop error , non syntax

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, freeze

I have problem with this class (sorry for really messy code). 
After while(scan.hasNextLine()) code is done with loop , nothing happens. Code just freezes. Java doesn't report any error , but it should continue running.

Class is implementation of server which collects messages with Rock, Paper or Scissors from socket , randomly makes it's own decisions and sends it back to client.

```
while (keepRunning == true) {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scan.nextLine();
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
        listForServer.add(line);
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.contentEquals("SHAPE") == false) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        Random rn = new Random();
        int n = 2 - 0 + 1;
        int i = rn.nextInt() % n;
        int randomNum = 0 + i;
        if (randomNum == 0) {
            shape = "Rock";
            randServerList.add(shape);
        } else if (randomNum == 1) {
            shape = "Paper";
            randServerList.add(shape);
        } else {
            shape = "Scissors";
            randServerList.add(shape);
        }
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Shapes are chosen");
    System.out.println("Client has send " + (counter - 1) + "shapes");
}
```

Comment: Please narrow the code to the relevant part instead of posting your whole program. What does your debugger say ?

Comment: In `while(keepRunning = true)` `=` is assignment operator, `==` is comparison. To avoid such mistakes simply use `while(keepRunning)`

Comment: Thanks for tip. Debugger doesn't say anything , he should print "Shapes are chosen" message , but instead he just stop after while loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the java docs of [hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())

Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Since you have line = scan.nextLine() in the loop it and you scan is open it will continue to wait for the input. Hence the code blocked and you don't see any output.